# Nette Framework - custom attribute macros

Tags: php, nette

What is the best way to define new attribute macros in the [Nette Framework](http://nette.org/)?

Moreover, would it be possible to do so in the config file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

define your own macro is really simple in Nette Framework,
first you must create MacroSet:

```
$latte = new Nette\Latte\Engine;
$set = new Nette\Latte\Macros\MacroSet($latte->compiler);
```

then create new Macro with args:

```
$set->addMacro('if', 'if (%node.args):', 'endif');
```

And solution for your second question:

```
Class MyMacroSet extends Nette\Latte\Macros\MacroSet
{
    public static function install(Nette\Latte\Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $compiler->addMacro('if', 'if (%node.args):', 'endif');
    }
}
```

and in config.neon you can register your macroSet:

```
nette.latte:
                setup:
                        - MyMacroSet::install($service->compiler)
```