# How to create a function in Latte?

Tags: php, latte

I have been trying to get started with Latte but there is literally close to no real documentation. I am looking for a way to create functions just like in Smarty. As far as I understand this has to be done with Macros, however there are close to no examples whatsoever. Could anyone help me out / point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,

Comment: I can see quite a lot of documentation and simple examples on the projects homepage. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: Poor documentation is usually a good hint for me to keep walking. Why bother with latte if it has poor documentation and you want to start with it? Why not just go elsewhere?

Comment: I am looking for a proper way to create a function / macro, however, I have no clue how to create one and call one in the template itself.

Comment: Hi here is almost same question: [latte macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456439/nette-framework-custom-attribute-macros) maybe it help.